# Is singleton set open in $\Bbb Q$ with subspace topology and what are the connected sets of this topology?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

I think {$x$} is not open in $\Bbb Q$ as if I take any open set $G$ in $\Bbb R$, then $G$ intersection $\Bbb Q$ is never the singleton set {$x$} as {$x$} is not open in $\Bbb R$ and any open set in $\Bbb R$ has infinitely many rationals in it.
Am I correct?

One more question what are the connected sets in this subspace topology on $\Bbb Q$ ?

Comment: You don't consider $\mathbb R$ if you are considering $\mathbb Q$ as a topological space. If you put any topology on $\mathbb Q$ then there is an open set containing $x$. (Why?) Take the intersection of that set with the singleton and we get that the singleton is open in the subspace topology.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct.

$\{x\}$ is not open in $\Bbb{Q}$ .

Now I claim only connected subsets of $\Bbb{Q}$ are singleton subsets.

Suppose, $A\subset \Bbb{Q}$ is connected.

Let, $x\neq  y \in \Bbb{Q} $

Then $\exists r\in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{ Q} $ such that $x<r<y$

And $A = A\cap (-\infty , r) \cup A\cap (r, \infty) $

Implies $A$ is not connected.

Hence, all connected components are one point sets.

Comment: Personally, I'd also consider the empty subset to be connected.  (Though I'm aware of the point of view that a topological space must be nonempty.)

Comment: The empty set is most definitely a topological space.

Comment: Why are you considering $\mathbb R$? We can put a topology on $\mathbb Q$ and the singleton set is open in the subspace topology.

Comment: @S. G    Since I am considering A as subset of Q, the open sets used to show the disconnectedness should come from open sets of Q(similar to the case of Q which has open sets as Q intersection open set of R ), but here you have taken (r, infinity) which is open in R but not Q. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

To see that the singletons are not open, note that for each $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, there is a sequence $q_n\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{x\}$ with $q_n\to x$, so that $x$ is contained in the closure of $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{x\}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{x\}$ is not equal to its closure, it is not closed and therefore its complement $\{x\}$ is not open.

$\mathbb{Q}$ is [*totally disconnected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space), which means that its only connected subsets are the singletons. To see this, let $A\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ be connected and suppose that $A$ is not a singleton. Then there exists $a,b\in A$ with $a\neq b$. Without loss of generality, assume that $a<b$.

Since $A$ is connected and contained in $\mathbb{R}$, it is path-connected, so there exists continuous $p:[0,1]\to A$ with $p(0)=a$ and $p(1)=b$. Choose $v\in(a,b)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. It then follows from the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) that there exists $c\in[0,1]$ with $p(c)=v\notin\mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction. So the connected components of $\mathbb{Q}$ are the singletons.